# securely passing sensitive data from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

My scenario looks like this, I'm showing database paginated grid on the screen.
I want add a button to download CSV spreadsheet .
so I coded something like this:

```js
$(function(){
 
 var  file_complete = false;
 var  final_sql = $('.initiate_download').val();
 var  orderby = $('#search_submit').data('orderby');

  
 var  $posturl = $url + "index.php/Spawner/launch_spawner";  
 

 $('#downloadModal').modal('hide');
  
 $('.initiate_download').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#pleaseWait').html($html);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
   $.ajax({       // initiate download
    url:  $posturl,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
     final_sql: final_sql,
     orderby: orderby,
     report: $report 
      },
    success: function(data) {
     var download_id = data;
     // console.log(download_id);
     check_download_status(download_id);
    }
   })
  }, 2000);
 })
});
```

```html
 <div class="row top-buffer">   
  
    <button id="search_submit" class="btn btn-primary initiate_download" type="submit" value="<?php echo $sql; ?>"    data-orderby="<?php echo $orderby;?>"  name="final_sql_lic" >Download List</button>
 
       <span id="pleaseWait">  </span>        
  
  </div>
```

it works fine, but the problem is that you can view SQL with view page option, is there a way around it ?

Comment: If we can see your SQL query in the HTML, you should rethink your design.

Comment: if you're running sql that's coming from the client, good luck with keeping your server alive...

Answer (score 2):

What most people do is they don't embed the SQL on page, but instead expose URLs that handle the SQL stuff behind the scenes.

In your example, you might create a page like this:
`http://website.com/api/csv?select=col1,col2,col3&orderBy=someColumn&where=someCondition`

Then your php will take those parameters and generate the sql based off of those and run the query.  Make sure you securely handle the input to avoid SQL injection (See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

The problem with your current scenario is that someone viewing your source  will plainly see that you're passing SQL directly to your server, meaning they can generate their own SQL like: `DROP TABLE table1, table2;` or worse.